# .NET Native serialization code missing for List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, win-universal-app, datacontractserializer, .net-native

In a Windows 10 Universal app I'm getting an error when trying to use the `DataContractSerializer`

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.SByte]' cannot be
>   serialized, serialization code for the type is missing.Consult the SDK
>   documentation for adding it as a root serialization type.

I'm not using the DCS directly, but within the context of a WCF call to a service operation.

I haven't been able to work out what runtime directive(s) would fix this problem.  The following doesn't help:

```
<Type Name="System.Collections.Generic.List{System.SByte}" 
      Dynamic="Required Public" 
      DataContractSerializer="Required Public" 
      Browse="Required All" 
      Serialize="Required All"/>
```

Comment: Is this library a Portable Class Library? We have a bug in Update 1 such that some PCLs will never have any serialization data generated for them.

Comment: No, it's not a PCL.  I've modified the directive per the answer from KooKiz below, and now get an InvalidOperationException at compile time with message "Found multiple matches for <>f_AnonymousType0`2".  Where the app or referenced libraries are defining this anonymous type is a mystery.  What are recommended resources for debugging these problems?

Comment: It may be fastest if we're able to sort this out directly via email. You can catch us here: dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Comment: In tracing messages between client and service it looks like I might be getting this error when trying to deserialize an enum type which is decorated with the FlagsAttribute.  Is there any possibility these are somehow seen as List<SByte>?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn627478(v=vs.110).aspx), your declaration of `List<SByte>` is incorrect. You only have to indicate the number of generic parameters, not their actual type:

```
<Type Name="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've made this change and now get an InvalidArgumentException at compile time due to multiple matches found.  One step forward, one step back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
<Namespace Name="System" Serialize="Required Public" DataContractSerializer="Required All"/>

<Namespace Name="'System.Collections.Generic" DataContractSerializer="Required All">
  <TypeInstantiation Name="List"
        Arguments="System.SByte" Serialize="Public" DataContractSerializer="Required All"/>
</Namespace>
```

In a similar situation it helped me.
I used these links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600639(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: - [https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/serialization.html#](https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/serialization.html#)

Comment: - [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/989159c7-a440-42ac-8e45-ef86a053e034/uwp-net-native-compile-fails-with-errors-about-found-multiple-matches-for?forum=wpdevelop](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/989159c7-a440-42ac-8e45-ef86a053e034/uwp-net-native-compile-fails-with-errors-about-found-multiple-matches-for?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: welcome to SO @Andrej. You can edit the answer so all links are inside and not in additional comments. Also, a lot of links are not considered helpful as they may become stale over time. If your text contains the relevant info from the links that's fine ...

Comment: @Stefan Hegny thank you for the advice. Unfortunately I do not have permission (low reputation) to add inside message more than one link.

Comment: I see, I thought that editing your own posts would be possible regardless of reputation...